# how to make a mainwindow as a MDI parent in qt

Tags: qt, mdiparent, qmainwindow

how to make a mainwindow as a MDI parent in Qt creator

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmdiarea.html) widget as a central widget of your parent window. Smth like this:

```
QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow;
mainWindow->setCentralWidget(mdiArea);
```

better example is here: [MDI Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/mainwindows-mdi.html)

hope this helps, regards